# Analogy to solidity msg.sender and address

Tags: smart-contract

what are alternatives in EOS to solidity address and msg.sender?
for address is it account_name or?

Cheers

Comment: @Bida do the linked question's answers satisfy your question or is this different?

Comment: @TeeAttack42 yes, this is what I was wondering, cheers

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in EOS the account is the main identifier. It is up to 12 characters and the characters can be any small case letter a-z and any digit in the range 1-5 and a period/dot .

The maximum length of an account name is 12 characters and most are exactly 12 characters and don't have a period in them. Shorter account names and account names with a dot in them are premium account names and cost money to register.

Comment: hi Ami, tnx for answer! So if I would like to have information about sender of action request in action, i would need to provide account_name of sender through action parameters? There is no another way?

Comment: Yes, look for some examples in the main project source code, specifically in the contracts folder.